# Trello: How can I create all day event?

Tags: trello, google-calendar, calendar

I've enabled calendar feature in Trello, but for each card I have to define date and time.

When I import this calendar to google calendar, then each event/card take 1 hour.

Is there any way how to create all day event?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Trello feature related to cards in a list or Google Calendar feature "All day" calendar event.

Comment: I can't in trello just type date without time and create "all day" event, you have to specify time.

Comment: What is wrong with leaving out both date and time?  Put the Date in the card title, but that will not show in the calendar.  Otherwise, you have to pick a standard time that everyone understands as "all day"

Comment: When you export your calendar, these evens are default defined as 1 hour event, I want to have all day event. Try open your calendar in gmail or outlook. You get no all day event from trello and that's what I am talking about.